Limit number of characters in QTextEdit
ALL,
Is there a way to limit the number of characters for QTextEdit?
If I have a database where a field is char(50), I'd like the application to have 50 characters limit and not the DB triggering the insertion failure.
EDIT:
As far as I understand I should be catching https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtextedit.html#textChanged. However, this documentation doesn't say whether it is fired on the pasting the text from Clipboard.
Just looking to mimic the native Windows behavior where only user actions , i.e. entering the text or pasting the text will prevent extra characters to appear. Setting the text or appending the text should continue working not matter what...
TIA!!!

@musicamante, yes, it is. Thx. Will it allow the setting/appending text to function disregarding the maximum length? Or I will have to do more tweaking?

Why closure? Not everything is explained...

Just block signals from the textedit while setting the text programmatically.

@musicamante, ok, so use the flag and check it? Thx.

No need for a flag, as the textChanged signal only has external effects (unlike, for instance, the documents' signals); use QSignalBlocker.

@musicamante, not sure what you mean. If I call setText() it will go thru the textChanged signal as well, right? So if I block it from there the text will not be changed. Am I missing something? Maybe you can put some code for me to see?

QSignalBlocker does as its name suggests: it just blocks signals, it doesn't prevent actions that may cause that signal. Note that it won't block "any signal whatsoever", it will just block signal that may be emitted by the "blocked widget" used in its constructor. If you call setText() while blocking signals, the text will be changed anyway, but no signal that may eventually be caused by that call will be emitted by that "blocked widget". QSignalBlocker works only as long as it exists: it's normally created as a local object within a function, so that it will only block signals until »

» that function returns, since it goes out of scope and is then automatically destroyed: you create it when you want to begin the blocking, then either you manually destroy it when you want to restore signal emission within the function, or leave it to the destructor when the function returns. Python bindings even provide a context manager, which is quite handy: everything executed within its with QSignalBlocker(qobj): will prevent signal emission from qobj, which will eventually be restored outside of that block (assuming that the object wasn't previously blocked before that).

@musicamante, understood thx.
